# Copy images to send to Parallel.For()

Tags: c#

I've been looking everywhere and I cant seem to get rid of the image is used elsewhere,

I need to create copies that are independent and send them to the parallel for

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(1, processorCount + 1, (i, loopState) =>
{
    Bitmap copied = new Bitmap(imageBitmaps[0]);
    SimpleProcessParalelFrames(1, i, processorCount, keyFrames.Count, keyFrames, generatedVideo, transforma, segment.Name, new[] {copied});
});
```

Comment: If you are getting a error you need to include the details of the exact error you are getting.

Comment: "Object is currently in use elsewhere", is the common error when your object is locked somewhere, i've read, many threads, but nothing has a real solution.